# JQuery highlight the radio button which is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a radio group of male and female value

How can I obtain the current selected value via jquery and then apply a class to the radio input that represents thus vale so that it is highlighted?

For those querying: I am making the radio input appear as buttons and hiding the radio icon, so I want to apply a class to it in order to show a selected state on the currently selected button.

I have no control over the form to make them actual buttons so I am simply restyling the look of the radio inputs I am given.

for those requesting code;

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> <span style="btn btn-default">Male</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> <span style="btn btn-default">Female</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> <span style="btn btn-default">Other</span>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Show up your code!

Comment: `$('input[name="gender"]').change(function(){ $(this).addClass('yourClassName');})`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
var selectedInput = $('input[name="gender"]:checked');
var value = selectedInput.val();
selectedInput.addClass('highlighted');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.on('change')` to track the radio button checked event, and `addClass()` method to add class on selection, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type='radio']").on('change', function(e) {
     $("input[type='radio']").removeClass('myClass');
    $("input[type='radio']").next('span').removeClass('highlight');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).addClass('myClass');
        $(this).next('span').addClass('highlight');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> <span style="btn btn-default">Male</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> <span style="btn btn-default">Female</span><br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> <span style="btn btn-default">Other</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just style it with css.

your html:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> <span style="btn btn-default">Male</span><br>
```

css:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + span {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ":checked" CSS pseudo class instead of adding a class with JavaScript, like so:

```
input[type=radio][name=gender]:checked {
  // Your styles
}
```